# CSS Animation not being applied in given path

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, animate.css

I'm trying to apply an animation to background of this page. However, I'm finding that it isn't applied on right place, rather then applying on background its being applied to the `h2` tag. I have no idea what could be causing it.

Body animation code:

```css
body{
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(-30deg, #03a9f4 0%, #3a78b7 50%,
    #262626 50%, #607d8b 100%);
    filter: hue-rotate(120deg);
    animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate
{
    0%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

h2 tag code:

```css
.list h2{
    text-align: center;
    background: #03a9f4;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the animation set on the body is not working on the body element itself, but on its children.

If we put in a div element that has the given background and animation instead that gets the colors animated and of course its CSS settings do not affect the h2 and any other elements.

Here is a snippet. Some of the CSS could be tidied up but this is to give the idea and a first example.

```css
body, div.bg {
  width:100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-bottom: 6%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
}

div.bg::before{
  content: '';
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-bottom: 6%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(-30deg, #03a9f4 0%, #3a78b7 50%, #262626 50%, #607d8b 100%);
  animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
  z-index:-1;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes animate

{

0%

{
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
}

100%
{
    filter: hue-rotate(359deg);
}
}


.list h2{
  text-align: center;
  background: #03a9f4;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="list">
  <h2>h2 element</h2>
</div>
</body>
```